# what does the error 'Incorrect number of bindings supplied' in python using SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I keep getting the error:

```
Incorrect number of bindings supplied
```

Ccan anyone tell me what this means?

The code where I am getting the error is:

```
import sqlite3
statement=''
name=''
def update_data(values):
    with sqlite3.connect("mrsimms.db")as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = statement
        cursor.execute(sql,values)
        db.commit()

def update_product_type():
    statement= "Update Stock set Type=? where Name=?"
    Type=input("Please enter the updated type: ")
    data=(Type)
    update_data(data)
    print()
    again=input('Would you like to do anything else?(y/n) ')
    if again =='y':
        menu()
    else:
        print()
def update_product_retail_price():
    statement= "Update Stock set RetailPrice=? where Name=?"
    RetailPrice=input("Please enter the updated retail price: ")
    data=(RetailPrice)
    update_data(data)
    print()
    again=input('Would you like to do anything else?(y/n) ')
    if again =='y':
        menu()
    else:
        print()

def update_product_number_in_stock():
    statement= "Update Stock set NumberInStock=? where Name=?"
    NumberInStock=input("Please enter the updated number in stock: ")
    data=(NumberInStock)
    update_data(data)
    print()
    again=input('Would you like to do anything else?(y/n) ')
    if again =='y':
        menu()
    else:
        print()


def menu():
    Name = input("Please enter the name of the product you wish to update: ")
    print()
    print('1. Update the product type')
    print('2. Update the product retail price')
    print('3. Update number in stock ')
    print('9. Quit ')
    print()
    choice=int(input('What would you like to do? '))
    if choice == 1:
        update_product_type()
    elif choice == 2:
        update_product_retail_price()
    elif choice == 3:
        update_product_number_in_stock()
    elif choice == 9:
        print()

menu()
```

i am trying to edit a record on my database and I can't see what I've done wrong. Any help would be lovely, I am new to using databases with Python.

Comment: That code doesn't even work, because you're not passing `statement` into `update_data`.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing in a *single* string as second parameter to the `sql.execute()` call; strings are sequences too, with a length equal to the number of characters in the string.

You want to make it a tuple instead, and you tried to, but forgot a comma:

```
data=(NumberInStock)
```

should be

```
data=(NumberInStock,)
```

(and similar errors in several places).

Next, your queries actually take **two** parameters; you must pass in a value for the `Name` part of your queries as well.

See your first query, for example:

```
statement= "Update Stock set Type=? where Name=?"
```

Here you take a type and a name, but only pass in a value for the type:

```
Type=input("Please enter the updated type: ")
data=(Type)
update_data(data)
```

You need to add in a value for the name parameter too:

```
Type = input("Please enter the updated type: ")
data = (Type, Name)
update_data(data)
```

where `Name` should be added as a parameter to your functions, and you should pass in `statement` as an argument to your `update_data()` function; don't use globals here:

```
import sqlite3

def update_data(sql, values):
    with sqlite3.connect("mrsimms.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, values)
        db.commit()

def update_product_type(Name):
    statement = "Update Stock set Type=? where Name=?"
    Type = input("Please enter the updated type: ")
    data = (Type, Name)
    update_data(data)

def update_product_retail_price(Name):
    statement = "Update Stock set RetailPrice=? where Name=?"
    RetailPrice = input("Please enter the updated retail price: ")
    data = (RetailPrice, Name)
    update_data(statement, data)

def update_product_number_in_stock():
    statement = "Update Stock set NumberInStock=? where Name=?"
    NumberInStock = input("Please enter the updated number in stock: ")
    data = (NumberInStock, Name)
    update_data(data)


def menu():
    while True:
        Name = input("Please enter the name of the product you wish to update: ")
        print()
        print('1. Update the product type')
        print('2. Update the product retail price')
        print('3. Update number in stock ')
        print('9. Quit ')
        print()
        choice = int(input('What would you like to do? '))

        if choice == 1:
            update_product_type(Name)
        elif choice == 2:
            update_product_retail_price(Name)
        elif choice == 3:
            update_product_number_in_stock(Name)
        elif choice == 9:
            print()
            break

        again = input('Would you like to do anything else? (y/n) ')
        if again.lower() != 'y':
            break
```

I've moved out question to do anything else out to the menu, using a loop instead of recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the number of variables in your SQL query is the same as the number of values that you're providing. You seem to be calling `update_data` with only one value instead of the necessary number of values.

When the line `cursor.execute(sql,values)` is executed it needs to have both the query and the correct number of values. For example, a query `"Update Stock set NumberInStock=? where Name=?"` needs to have two values: one for each question mark.

Otherwise you'll get an error that you're not providing the correct number of bindings.